# How to block score to not go below zero?

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c

I'm making a word game but I can't figure out how to make zero the final point in the basic scoring I've created. The user must not exceed a minus in his or her score, thus the lowest score can only be zero...

```
- (IBAction)btncheck:(id)sender {
NSString *answer = [_textbox.text stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@" " withString:@""]
if([answer isEqualToString:@""]){
}
else  
if ([answer isEqualToString:@"q"]) {
    // String is correct, resign keyboard
    _keyboard.hidden = YES;
    _textXclear.hidden = YES;
    //Perfect button
    [_closeone setHidden:NO];
    [_wrongone setHidden:YES];
    score = score +100;
    [scoreLabel setText:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"score: %d", score]];
   coins = coins +5;
    [coinsLabel setText:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", coins]];
}
else {
    [_wrongone setHidden:NO];
    score = score -5 ;
    [scoreLabel setText:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"score: %d", score]];
   closeonechange.text = @"Correct!";

}
```

Oh and if the score becomes zero the user must only receive 1 coin.

How will I do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just use `MAX`

```
score = MAX(0, score - 5);
```

Comment: I put this in if correct " score = MAX (score +100, 0);" and this in else wrong "score = MIN(score -55, 0);" and it worked But how do i -4 coins if score is equal to 0?

Comment: `if (0 == score) { coins -= 4; }`

Answer (score 0):

Are you looking for this?

```
score = MAX(0, score - 5);
if (score == 0) coins += 1;
```

Comment: The first part is good, but the second part for the coins is not working!

Comment: I edited my answer. There was a typo.

Comment: if (score == 0) coins = 1; this worked

Comment: I thought you meant user should receive 1 coin instead of set to 1 coin.

Answer (score 0):

```
score = ((score-5) < 0) ? 0 : (score-5);
```